# What part of the souls receives pleasure when saying a Bracha on smelling?

Tags: blessing, mysticism-kabbalah, chasidut-hasidism, tractate-brachot, smell

BH

What part of the souls receives pleasure when smelling something?(Ie. Nefesh Ruach Neshama Chaya Yechida? And is it the part in the NRNChY of the Nefesh Elokit? or is it the NRNChY of the natural soul?)

Comment: Pleasure doesn't locate to a single place, it _permeates_, starting from Keter. However, perhaps there is a more specific answer to your question, so may we ask: what caused you to ask this?

Comment: @Nahum that gemara discusses the pleasure of the scent, not the pleasure of the bracha, nor does it hint that a specific part of the neshama experiences said pleasure. However, the tag is berachot so maybe you're right! Let's see what David says

Comment: I meant what part of the soul revives pleasure for smell and not the Bracha just the smell. (ie. what part of the soul? Nefesh ruach neshama Chaya Yechida) and if yes is it the NRNChY of the animal soul or the G-dly soul?

Comment: @David thanks for the clarification, please [edit](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/140401/edit) that information into the question :)